# Need Help Integrating Interstitial ads in Spritekit iOS Game

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

I am making a game using Xcode and SpriteKit, I am integrating ads using admob and have all of the code working for the banner ads and have been able to get the interstitial ads to work as well. My problem is telling the game when to display the interstitial ad. The ad is in GameViewController but I need to call the showAd() method from GameScene.swift How would I go about calling a function from GameViewController in GameScene. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance, Zach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `GameViewController`, setup a notification observer in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` like so:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showAd), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showAd"), object: nil)

}
```

Then in your GameScene, call this when you want the function in `GameViewController` to be run:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showAd"), object: nil)
```

Keep in mind that you need to have a function to be called inside your `GameViewController`. `showAd` is just a placeholder for whatever function you want to be run inside your `GameViewController`.

Hopefully this helps!