# Interstitial Ads SpriteKit

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, admob

Can someone please help me? I really want to add interstitial ads to my spritekit game but have no clue. I have tried a lot of tutorials and even google firebase but i cant seem to get to work.

Comment: I've added interstitial ads to my SpriteKit game. Where exactly are you struggling? Which framework are you using (e.g. AdMob)?

Comment: Which tutorials have you tried? Please can you post some code here that you have tried?

Comment: Ive tried videos on youtube @mike

Comment: Yes adMob @floschliep, i want to call the ads in the gameOverScene and i need a proper code for the viewController

Comment: @MatthewRamsaroop Check this answer out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40164206/6728196 I'm assuming that you already have the code to make the ad show up, but you're having trouble running the code from a scene rather than viewController

Comment: @Nik I don't think that's a good solution. First of all, viewWillLayoutSubviews is definitely not a place to subscribe to notifications. That said, I don't think notifications should be used here. This isn't a to-many relationship but a one-to-one relationship. I would suggest delegation or a simple callback.

Comment: @Nik how do I use a simple call back or Delegation ?

Comment: @floschliep I made this example using advice from others. If it's incorrect, I can change it or remove it, however it works for me

Comment: @Nik It's not technically incorrect, as it will get the job done, but that doesn't mean it's a good solution. Take a look at the answer I posted below. I would argue either solution I suggested produces much cleaner code that serves the purpose in a better way and will also produce a cleaner stack trace while debugging.

Comment: @floschliep I agree completely, however I'm still gonna leave my answer here for reference. Won't be referencing to that anymore though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdMob presents interstitial ads using view controllers and you can't present view controllers using SpriteKit. You'll need to use UIKit to present the interstitial ad. How you connect your SpriteKit and UIKit code is up to you, I'd either use delegation or a callback.

**Delegation**

```
protocol MyGameSceneDelegate: class {
    func gameDidFinish()
}

class MyGameScene: SKScene {
    weak var gameDelegate: MyGameSceneDelegate?

    func finishGame() {
        self.gameDelegate?.gameDidFinish()
    }
}
```

**Callback**

```
class MyGameScene: SKScene {
    var gameDidFinish: (() -> Void)?

    func finishGame() {
        self.gameDidFinish?()
    }
}
```

If you're not familiar with these terms I highly recommend learning about common design patterns in Swift (or Objective-C). Apple has some great resources for both languages and there are tons of books that will help you get started with iOS development.